# probability of the union and intersection of sets A and B

Tags: probability, set-theory

If I have two sets A and B and take

$$ P((A\cap B) \cap (A\cup B)),$$

is this the same as $P(A\cup B)$?

Comment: Not quite: $(A \cap B) \cap(A\cup B) = (A \cap B) $ while $(A \cap B) \cup(A\cup B) = (A \cup B) $

Comment: Draw a [Venn Diagram](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venn_diagram) of the two events and compare.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Venn diagrams, you can easily see, $(A \cap B) \cap(A\cup B) = (A \cap B) $
 $\\ $

But $(A \cap B) = (A \cup B)$, only when $A$ and $B$ are subsets of each other, i.e they both have the same elements.$\\$

Hence, $P(A \cap B) = P(A \cup B)$, only when A and B have the same elements.

Or $P(A \cap B) \cap(A\cup B) = P(A \cup B) $, only when A and B have the same elements.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

- Notice that if $C \subset D$, then $C \cap D = C$.
- For $A \cap B$ and $A \cup B$, one of them is a subset of the other. Using the first pointer, you should be able to simplify your expression.

Comment: How do you know

Comment: give it and attempt to prove it,, to prove two sets are equal, you show that they are subset of each other. To show that a set $E$ is a subset of $F$, you take an element of $E$ and show that it is an element of $F$.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not the same because the union contains all the elements in the intersection, but not the vice versa; therefore their intersection is actually the intersection of the original sets.