# Proving Conditional Probability of the intersection and union

Tags: self-study, conditional-probability

I want to prove that:
$$P(A \cap B|A \cup B)\le P ((A \cap B)|A)$$
I know that 
$$P(A \cap B|A \cup B) = \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A \cup B)}$$

I have tried using formula that consider them as subsets but seem to be going around in circles. Can anyone give me a few pointers to the theorems that would be useful?

Comment: Once again, [as in your previous question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/447238), this is easy to do by drawing a Venn diagram because it clearly shows the denominator in the left fraction is no less than that in the right fraction whereas they share the same numerator.

Answer (score 2):

Using the second equation that you wrote, you want to prove that

$$\frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A \cup B)} \le \frac{P(A \cap B)}{P(A)}$$

If $P(A \cap B)=0$, then we are done. Suppose not, then this is equivalent to

$$P(A) \le P(A \cup B).$$

Try to prove this last inequality by showing that a set is another set's subset.